# How to make express router work in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, angular

I am trying to connect with Express server using Angular 5 but it seems that it is not working. I want to develop an Mean Stack Project

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Parses incomong requests like submitting a form
const path = require('path');

const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Now listening for requests: " + port)
});
```

**/server/routes/api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('api works');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
```

When i tried to run **ng build** and **nodemon** then go to http://localhost:3000/ I see what is inside the content of app.component.html

[image]

I think I should see:

[image]

The code above works in Angular 4 but not Angular 5. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this repository please https://github.com/NourEddinKhanjar/Nodejs-and-angular5-CRUD-project

Comment: why are you using express router, angular itself has a router

Comment: @akhilaravind I am trying to create MeaN Stack Project

Comment: create api in express and use http methods in angular to call the api